Select2 does not show my selected data on the screen
I'm stuck on a problem and I was wondering if you could help me.
I have an ASP .NET MVC system, and I have a widget screen with the function of editing a widget.
The call to edit a widget is in a PartialView, I can bring up all the fields filled in by the user, but in my select id=garagens-sel which I use select2, I have an array with 3 garages, but I can't show it these 3 garages in my select2 box selected. I've tried several things but I still can't show these garages on the screen. But if I look at the inspect element in the browser, I can see the 3 garages with their ids in the value and with the selected property applied.
My EditarCard.cshtml:


 <div id="selecao-garagens" style="flex-direction: column; gap: 8px">
     <label class="custom-label">Garagens (para considerar todas as garagens, não selecione nenhum item)</label>
     <select id="garagens-sel" name="garagens-sel" class="select2 form-control select2-multiple" multiple >
             @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Garagens)
             {
                 List<Guid> garagensSelecionadas = Model.GaragensSelecionadas != null ? ((List<Guid>)Model.GaragensSelecionadas) : new List<Guid>();
                 <option value="@item.ID" @(garagensSelecionadas.Contains(item.ID) ? "selected" : "")>@item.Nome</option>
             }
     </select>

     <label class="custom-label" style="display: flex; gap: 4px; align-items: center;">
         <input id="considerar-ativos" type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;"    @(Model?.SomenteAtivos == true ? "checked" : "") />
         Considerar somente ativos
     </label>
 </div>



My JS:


        $(document).ready(function () {
        ...
            const widget = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model));
            console.log(widget);

            $('#garagens-sel').select2({
                multiple: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
                placeholder: 'Selecione',
            });

            $('#eventos-sel').select2({
                multiple: true,
                closeOnSelect: false,
                placeholder: 'Selecione',
            });

            if (widget) {
                ...
                $('#garagens-sel').val(widget.GaragensSelecionadas).trigger('change');
                $('#eventos-sel').val(widget.EventosSelecionados).trigger('change');
                $('#considerar-ativos').prop('checked', widget.SomenteAtivos);

                const iconeClasse = widget.Icone.split(' ').filter(cls => cls !== 'float-right').join(' ');
                $('.selecao-icone i').each(function() {
                    const iconClasses = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').filter(cls => cls !== 'float-right').join(' ');
                    if (iconClasses === iconeClasse) {
                        $(this).parent().addClass('selecionado');
                    }
                });
            }
            .....
            }



This is the PartialView call that is on my other html page:
Home.cshtml:


     <aside id="sidebar_novo_widget" style="padding: 32px;">
    </aside>
 
 $('.edit-card').on('click', function () {
     var widgetId = $(this).data('id');

     defaultSidebar.hide();
     createWidgetSidebar.show();

     $('#sidebar_novo_widget').empty();
     $('#sidebar_novo_widget').append(`
     <div style="display: flex; align-items: center; height: 100%;">
         <img id="loading" src="/images/Spinner-1s-60px.gif" class="transparent" height="60" width="60" style="margin:auto" />
     </div>
     `);

     $.ajax({
         url: `/Dashboard/EditarCardView/${widgetId}`,
         method: "GET",
         success: function (response) {
             $('#sidebar_novo_widget').empty();
             $('#sidebar_novo_widget').append(response);
         }
     });
 });



If you need any further information please let me know. Thank you very much!
Thats the example of my data showed on my console.log(widget)


{Cor:"#ea0ba3",
DataAtualizacao:"2024-06-12T21:17:32.029Z",
DataCriacao:"2024-05-23T20:35:59.667Z",
EventosSelecionados:null,
GaragensSelecionadas:Array(3)
0:"6170e8ea-197e-434f-a165-c8bacd843777",
1:"c96f6aca-f150-45fa-a6a4-3e0eef99e060",
2:"15998f4e-0d4c-45b9-b622-b5f826ea2e87",
length:3,
[[Prototype]]:Array(0),
ID:"9045862b-8429-441d-b3e5-e868eb8c448d",
Icone:"fas fa-user-alt float-right",
Item:"Motoristas",
ModeloGrafico:null,
SomenteAtivos:true,
Tipo:"Quantidade",
TipoWidget:null,
Titulo:"Teste Card 2244",
tEmpresaID:"ac727277-25a2-441c-a2f1-4eb429d3b097"
}



how it should appear:

how is today:


Please create a minimal reproducible example
